# How do I connect to Palo Alto Global Protect VPN through command line?

Tags: c#, command-line, vpn

Client changed VPNs to Global Protect, so I have to build a new connection in code.

https://knowledgebase.paloaltonetworks.com/KCSArticleDetail?id=kA10g000000ClhQCAS

This is the only thing I can find on their CLI but there are no examples of how to use this from Windows CMD prompt. I need to be able to connect to them through code, usually that's through a cli for other VPNs. But if anyone has a suggestion for another way in c# I'm all ears.

I've looked at OpenConnect, but their latest version isn't a part of the windows version yet, so as much as I'd like to use it, that won't work.